# cffi load failure when trying to import PyOpenCL

Tags: python, windows, pyopencl

Here's the error that I get when I try to import pyopencl:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "PyOpenCLTest.py", line 6, in <module>
        import pyopencl as cl
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyopencl\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
        import pyopencl.cffi_cl as _cl
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyopencl\cffi_cl.py", line 39, in <module>
        from pyopencl._cffi import ffi as _ffi
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

My OS is Windows 7 (64-bit), and I'm currently using Python version 3.6.2.

My current graphics driver (AMD Radeon HD 7800) has the following specs:

- Radeon Settings Version 2017.0720.1902.3246
- OpenCL Version 22.19.662.4
- OpenGL version 6.14.10.13491
- Vulkan Driver Version 1.6.0
- Vulkan API Version 1.0.51
- AMD Mantle Version 9.1.10.0220
- AMD Mantle API Version 102400
- 2D Driver Version 8.1.1.1614
- Direct3D Version 9.14.10.01292

I have tried to import PyOpenCL after trying out a few different things:

- Repairing Visual Studio 2015
- Updating AMD driver
- Updating Intel driver (already up to date according to Intel Driver Update Utility)
- Getting Intel OpenCL SDK (Not sure if it's even being used)
- Installing PyOpenCL via easy_install
- Installing PyOpenCL via [this wheel file](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/pyopencl%E2%80%912017.2+cl21%E2%80%91cp36%E2%80%91cp36m%E2%80%91win_amd64.whl)
- Installing cffi via easy_install
- Installing cffi via [this wheel file](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/cffi%E2%80%911.10.0%E2%80%91cp36%E2%80%91cp36m%E2%80%91win_amd64.whl)

In addition, I'm having trouble running a cffi example from the cffi overview page (I get a CompileError), but that is its own can of worms.